# Need NPM Module that depends on babel 7, but my project uses babel 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, package.json

I am writing an NPM module that contains some React components and has @babel/core 7 as a dependency. I am testing out this module locally by linking it (via `npm link`) to an existing project and trying to import components from the module. At runtime though, I get the following error:

`Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version.`

My existing project and all of its dependencies are a bit older and still use babel 6. Is there any way for me to get around this without upgrading to babel 7? Thanks!

Comment: You could rewrite the second NPM module with babel 6.

Comment: Not so sure as to what your build workflow and dependencies look like for your library. Could you possibly include the `package.json` in your post?